# Internet Explorer 7 Certificate Error

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, internet-explorer

I understand that you could just fix the certificate issue or you could go to each pc and do the following:

Internet Options, Advanced, uncheck "Warn about certificate address mismatch".

But is there a way to set this in the GPO so that it does it for everyone?

Comment: Doesn't that defeat the object of having security warnings? I'd make this a training issue, personally.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just fix the certificate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the registry key you need to tweak:

```
HKEY_USERS\"USER  SID VALUE"\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\WarnonBadCertRecving
```

And Microsoft has a great article about making registry changes across your enterprise [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms954395.aspx)

Now, I do have to say that this strikes me as a poor idea. This removes pretty much all the fraud protection built into SSL-but after weighing the options, the tools are there to make the change.

Comment: +1 pointing out the bad-idea-ness and still answering the question.

Comment: +1 - The idea of disabling this security warning is a BAD idea!

Comment: an Enterprise-wide registry hack is not the way we want to go obviously. I'm going to look into the reasons for the certificate error and I'll post a follow up.

Comment: I followed up and found out that the problem revolves around intranet pc's hitting one IP and outside users hitting another. They decided to route the internal to a non-secure site to get around it.